# Find static 0 hazard

Tags: circuit-design, karnaugh-map

[image: hazard 0]

In this question, the top F=A'C'D' + A'B'C + ACD' + AB'C' is given in the question. With the question, im able to generate the kmap. Then in the kmap, i find F'=A'C'D + A'BC + ABC'+ ACD. To remove the hazard I added BD to get a hazard free function. Then I complemented it to get F = (A+C+D')(A+B'+C')(A'+B'+C)(A'+C'+D')(B'+D'). My question is that is the last pos function, able to get me a hazard free circuit and F = (A+C+D')(A+B'+C')(A'+B'+C)(A'+C'+D') can be used to detect the static 0 hazard in the function using the multisim online simulation.